# Getting 'client' not defined error while loading CSV file from cloud storage to Big Query table using Cloud Function Python

Tags: python

I am trying to load cloud csv file data to big query table using cloud function. However while deploying I am getting below error in log

```
line 25, in <module> load_job = client.load_table_from_uri( NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

**Below is the code -**

```
def my_function():
 print("step-1")
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 print("step0")
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
 client = bigquery.Client()
 print("step1")
# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
 table_id = "project-a-307309:DatasetA.TableD"
 print("step2")
 job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("Column_A", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("Column_B", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("Column_C", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("Column_D", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("Column_E", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://bq_dummy_data/Big Query Dummy Data.csv"
#print("step3")
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
#print("step4")
load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
#print("step5")
destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
my_function()
```

**Requirement.txt**

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-bigquery==2.11.0
google-cloud-storage==1.35.0
```

**Log**

```
2021-03-17T15:00:29.488Zfunction-2 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(_cli()) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__ return self.main(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main rv = self.invoke(ctx) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke return callback(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli app = create_app(target, source, signature_type) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 234, in create_app spec.loader.exec_module(source_module) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/workspace/main.py", line 25, in <module> load_job = client.load_table_from_uri( NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation to use at least 4 spaces. It's hard to see but it would appear that the line `load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(` is not indented and thus is not part of the function definition. Meaning `client` is indeed undefined at that point of your code.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel can you add your comment as an answer? this seems the root cause.

Comment: @JanHernandez, I'd rather the OP first confirm if all the lines preceding the call to `my_function()` do indeed belong to the function definition.

Comment: Thankyou @JustinEzequiel, it was indentation issue and it got resolved after using the spaces. Thankyou again.

Answer (score 0):

This looks not related with cloud APIS, as the user "Justin Ezequiel", the OP has non uniform indentation

> Please fix your indentation to use at least 4 spaces. It's hard to see but it would appear that the line load_job = client.load_table_from_uri( is not indented and thus is not part of the function definition. Meaning client is indeed undefined at that point of your code. – Justin Ezequiel yesterday